# Java Getting the Standard Output and Standard Error from a Seperate Process

Tags: java

I am starting a separate process in my Java program using `ProcessBuilder` This is were the process gets made:

```
Class klass=Program.class;
String[] output=new String[2];
 String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
 String javaBin = javaHome +
         File.separator + "bin" +
         File.separator + "java";
 String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
 String className = klass.getCanonicalName();

 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
         javaBin, "-cp", classpath, className);

 Process process = builder.start();
 process.waitFor();
```

Program.class is the following:

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hi!");
}
```

I want the standard output to produce `Hi!`, and the standard error, if I were to, for example, not add a semicolon after   `System.out.println("Hi!")` then the standard error would be:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

at Program.main(Program.java:6)
```

So, how can I do this? Ideally, the program converts these into two strings.

Thanks

Comment: Take a closer look at the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), it has an `inputStream` property, which is attached to the processes stdout.  You can also use `ProcessBuilder` to redirect the stderr through the stdout to make life easier

Comment: Can you use `inputStream` to add text input to the program, for example if you were using the `Scanner` class?

Comment: No, that would be what the `outputStream` property would be for...(yes, it sounds backwards, but it actually makes sense)

Comment: So you use `outputStream` to add input to the program, and `inputStream` to get the output? What?

Comment: Yep, try not to think about it to much.  Basically, `InputStream` has "read" methods and `OutputStream` has "write" methods, you want to "read" from and "write" to

Comment: OK, so how would I implement this into my code?

Comment: Like you would any time you try and read from an `InputStream`...

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968759/how-to-read-the-std-output-of-another-java-program-in-this-java-program/19969016#19969016), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226161/running-command-prompt-in-java-program-with-gui-netbeans/18226662#18226662) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716144/execute-java-file-with-runtime-getruntime-exec/23716208#23716208)

Comment: OK, works perfectly, but what about adding the standard error? As of right now, if there is an error, it just does nothing

Comment: You can use `Process#getErrorStream` and basically do the same thing as you would for the `inputStream` or use [`ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean))

Comment: Where would I add that in my current code? The code:

Comment: Oops, can't add that much code

Comment: ` BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));`

Comment: `String line = null;`

Comment: `waitFor` is blocking, so until the process exists, you won't see any output.  Have a lock at the last example, which uses a `Thread` to read the stream, but then blocks the calling thread by using `waitFor`

Comment: `while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);`

Comment: OK great, want to put all this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a closer look at the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class, it has an `inputStream` property, which is attached to the processes `stdout`. You can also use `ProcessBuilder` to redirect the `stderr` through the `stdout` to make life easier, using [`ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean))

You can write to the `Process` using its `outputStream` property (try not to think about it to much)...

Basically, you want to "read" the "output", via the `inputStream` and "write" to the "input" via the `outputStream`

Something like...

```
Class klass=Program.class;
String[] output=new String[2];
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
String javaBin = javaHome +
     File.separator + "bin" +
     File.separator + "java";
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String className = klass.getCanonicalName();

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
     javaBin, "-cp", classpath, className);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process process = builder.start();
int in = -1;
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
try {
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println((char)in);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with " + exitCode);
```

as an example

Comment: Could you add two strings titled `output` and `error` please?

Comment: Which include, obviously, the standard output and standard error

Comment: The example merges the stderr and stdin, so you can just use `Process#getInputStream`

Comment: `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);`